# How to automate an upstart script in Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, uwsgi, upstart

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) of setting nginx and uwsgi to serve a Flask application.
I ran into a problem after configuring upstart script.
It says:

> You can start the process immediately by typing:
>   `sudo start myproject`

I was trying to configure this stack inside docker container to keep my environment clean.

But when I type `sudo start myproject` (this script is made to run uwsgi server) it returns `0` and doesn't start anything.

I'm using docker, because I need to flexibly scale the load, and when it is needed I can run another container.  I use ubuntu-14.04 docker image. I want the job to start automatically.
As I found out from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254433/ubuntu-docker-container-with-upstart-and-syslog) docker is using it's own `/sbin/init`.

My question is how I can replace upstart script in this situation to make everything run with expected behaviour on start up and shot down.